# JQuery Validation Not Working

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using the same code for my contact us form, and trying to apply it to a quote form as well. I have duplicated the code, and added the data for AJAX. But it just does nothing, no errors at all, the form does submit. I am trying to test it by just clicking on the submit button i should get validation errors ie please enter in the information.

This works fine on my contact us form, i cannot find the issue!

http://www.aklogistics.co.uk/quote-cheap-man-and-van-hire-london.html

The JQuery code is in this file: http://www.aklogistics.co.uk/js/views/view.contact.js

Comment: There seems to be a problem with jquery.validation library, console returns 
`jquery.validation.min.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
    at a.validator.elementValue (jquery.validation.min.js:9)
    at a.validator.check (jquery.validation.min.js:9)
    at a.validator.checkForm (jquery.validation.min.js:9)
    at a.validator.form (jquery.validation.min.js:9)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (jquery.validation.min.js:9)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLFormElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)`
use updated jquery.validation js

Comment: i downloaded the latests validation js file and replaced it, but it's still the same. What's confusing is, why does it work fine for the contact us page, but not this page - its the same code! Only difference is the ajax data.

Comment: Found the solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<input type="checkbox" required="" aria-required="true">` this checkbox in 'Get Quote' page is not having any `id` and `name`, so jquery-validation is not able to reference it, that is why it is returning `type` undefined. Replace this checckbox with `<input type="checkbox" name="agree" id="agree" required="" aria-required="true" class="error">`

After a long debugging I found out this, give an id and name to your checkbox and validation will work accordingly.

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes 

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to this issue with .NET MVC Razor.  I found that I needed to add the id in the Razor @Html.CheckBox() helper:

```
    @Html.CheckBox("CheckBoxGroup", htmlAttributes: new { name = "CheckBoxGroup", id = "CheckBoxGroupItem1" })
    @Html.CheckBox("CheckBoxGroup", htmlAttributes: new { name = "CheckBoxGroup", id = "CheckBoxGroupItem2" })
```